# How to downgrade PHP to version 5.5 from .htaccess

Tags: php, apache-2.4, .htaccess

I had previously PHP 5.5 installed on my Ubuntu VPS and I upgraded to PHP7.1 by install PHP 7.1, Disabling the php5.5 and enabling the php7.1 module.

Its working fine but I want to run php5.5 in some folders but want to keep php7.1 as the default option.

I tried to add php5.5 to htaccess in following way with no success:

```
 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php .php7 .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Comment: you can't. The module you run depend on specific php libraries. If you want to support multiple versions installed on your system, you must use php-fpm for php and launch difference instances of it for each version.

Comment: @ezra-s, you should give that as an answer.

Comment: @ezra-s Thanks. So do I need to uninstall current 7.1 module for that or I can leverage it with php-fpm?

Comment: yes, you stop using mod_php and start using mod_proxy_fcgi pointing to the php-fpm server of each version. You can follow this link for the basic configuration details -> https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use several versions of `php` through `mod_php`, the reason is you can't load the same module twice or three times, apache will complain.

The best you can do is to unload `mod_php` and go with `mod_proxy_fcgi` + `PHP-FPM` (of each version) instead. Guide for configuring this setup is [here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM).

With apache configuration you can filter out which requests use which `php-fpm` backend of those you have configured with different versions.